# Removing any (first, middle, last, single) item in a CSV list via PHP's explode / implode

Tags: php, arrays, csv, explode, implode

```
$pieces = explode(",", $userList);

$key=array_search($deleteuser, $pieces);
if(FALSE !== $key)
{
    unset($pieces[$key]);
}
else
    return FALSE;

$userList = implode(",", $pieces);
```

I'm looking for inputs into how to rework this code to remove an element from a CSV list. The user should exist in this system and it should work fine even if there is one last user in the system (so no commands will exist).

Comment: You know, PHP has a [built-in csv parser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Probably better to use that, over using `explode`

Comment: Sorry guys - revised the title to make more sense... I ran into issues when it was the "final" (== only) item on the list and I watned to remove that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *guess* is that you had problems with the last/single item because you're reading the line from a file e.g. via fgets() and you didn't remove the trailing line break from the string. In that case you really should take a look at [fgetcsv()](http://docs.php.net/fgetcsv).
Anyway, to fix your function apply [trim()](http://docs.php.net/trim) to the input string (or to all array elements after the explode if you like) to remove whitespaces including line breaks.

```
<?php
echo '--', foo('thisone', 'a,bcd,thisone,e'), "--\n";
echo '--', foo('thisone', 'thisone,e'), "--\n";
echo '--', foo('thisone', "e, thisone\n"), "--\n";
echo '--', foo('thisone', 'thisone'), "--\n";
echo '--', foo('thisone', ''), "--\n";
echo '--', foo('thisone', 'a,thisone,b,thisone,c,thisone'), "--\n";

function foo($deleteuser, $userList) {
  $pieces = array_map('trim', explode(',', $userList));

  foreach( array_keys($pieces, $deleteuser) as $key ) {
    unset($pieces[$key]);
  }
  return  implode(',', $pieces);
}
```

prints

```
--a,bcd,e--
--e--
--e--
----
----
--a,b,c--
```

I've used [array_keys](http://docs.php.net/array_keys) instead of array_search() just in case the username can appear more than once in the list.

Comment: ... not to demean your effort Volker!

Answer (score 0):

i dont find the code so bad at all. but you could use for example:

```
$newUserList = str_replace(",,",",",str_replace($deleteuser,'',$userList));
```

but it isnt better then yours...

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
$arr = explode(',', $userList);
array_pop($arr);
$userList = implode(',', $arr);
```

But even though this asks your question, your implementation seems to solve "I need to remove a specific user from a CSV", not "I need to remove the last item in a CSV", what is the actual problem?

Comment: This always removes the first item while the op want to search for a specific item within the list.

Comment: This always removes the last item. Question is "Removing last item in a CSV list via PHP's explode / implode"

Comment: "it should work fine _even if_ there is one last user in the system"

Comment: It does work fine with only one user in the system. try this: `$users = "andrei";
$arr = explode(',', $users);
print_r($arr);`